# Как эффективно усечь голову файла?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, ос

Всем хорошо изветсна функция `truncate(file,size)`, изменяющая размер файла до заданного размера, путём усечения хвоста файла. Но как сделать то-же, только с усечением не хвоста файла а его головы?

Comment: Эффективно ни как. Только копированием данных ближе к началу и отсеканием опять же хвоста

Comment: Виртуально. Создаёте файл: `filename.begin` с начальным индексом начала файла. При чтении : обязалово прочитать индекс и перейти на него. Если файл со свободным доступом, то прийдётся копировать.

Comment: `tac | truncate`?

Answer (score 5):

В Linux есть системный вызов [`fallocate()`](http://ru.manpages.org/fallocate/2), который помимо своего основного назначения — резервирования пространства под файл может творить всякую магию. В частности начиная с 3.15 у него появился флаг `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE`, который и позволяет эффективно убирать часть данных из середины/начала файла без необходимости двигать их на диске. Например, удаление первого блока будет выглядеть так:

```
fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE, 0, 4096);
```

Поддерживаемые ФС: ext4 и XFS. У ФС также есть свои ограничения на значение начала смещения, обычно длина/смещение должны быть кратны началу блока ФС и для ext4 файл должен быть аллоцирован на основе экстентов (почти все файлы в современной ext4).

Для доступа из консоли к возможностям этого системного вызова есть одноимённая утилитка из `linux-utils` — [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html); `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` соответствует ключ `-с`.

#### Демонстрация действия.

Проверка, что ФС подходящая, определение размера блока:

```
$ mount | grep "$(df --output=source .)"
/dev/mapper/vg_main-gentoo_home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg_main-gentoo_home | grep -i 'block size'
Block size:               4096
```

Создание, тестового файла:

```
$ echo "file_start"  | cat - /dev/zero | dd bs=4k count=1 >>testfile 2>/dev/null
$ echo "file_middle" | cat - /dev/zero | dd bs=4k count=1 >>testfile 2>/dev/null
$ echo "file_end"    | cat - /dev/zero | dd bs=4k count=1 >>testfile 2>/dev/null
```

Проверка, что файл аллоцирован с помощью экстентов:

```
$ lsattr testfile
--------------e--- testfile
```

Состояние файла до операции:

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat alexander/tmp/testfile" /dev/mapper/vg_main-gentoo_home |grep -A3 EXTENTS 
EXTENTS:
(0-1):26281280-26281281, (2):26281396
alexander@goblin ~/tmp $ hexdump -C testfile
00000000  66 69 6c 65 5f 73 74 61  72 74 0a 00 00 00 00 00  |file_start......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  66 69 6c 65 5f 6d 69 64  64 6c 65 0a 00 00 00 00  |file_middle.....|
00001010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000  66 69 6c 65 5f 65 6e 64  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |file_end........|
00002010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003000
```

Удалим первый блок из файла:

```
$ fallocate -c -o 0 -l 4096 testfile
```

Состояние файла после операции:

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat alexander/tmp/testfile" /dev/mapper/vg_main-gentoo_home |grep -A3 EXTENTS 
EXTENTS:
(0):26281281, (1):26281396
$ hexdump -C testfile
00000000  66 69 6c 65 5f 6d 69 64  64 6c 65 0a 00 00 00 00  |file_middle.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  66 69 6c 65 5f 65 6e 64  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |file_end........|
00001010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000
```

Как видно, файл был обрезан с начала при этом все блоки остались на месте, данные на диске не двигались.

---

При всех плюсах `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` — это очень специфическая операция со множеством ограничений и на сегодняшний день AFAIK не имеет аналогов в других ОС. Так что к ней всегда следует предоставлять запасную реализацию с классическим алгоритмом:  «переписать все данные в начало и отсечь хвост».

Comment: "Не имеет аналогов" - да в той же NTFS такое можно элементарно делать небольшой корректировкой индексной записи, но здесь играет свою роль эффект неуловимого Джо. Это было бы полезно, если бы можно было вырезать блоки произвольной длины, но кому может понадобиться удалять целиком кластер (или несколько)? Особенно с учетом того, что размер кластера может варьироваться даже для однотипных дисков. Люди, которые замутили это чудо в Линуксе, явно просто маялись от безделья и не знали куда приложить руки.

Comment: @freim, «можно реализовать» почти на любой ФС, а вот API на уровне ОС я ни где не видел... может понадобиться при работе с уже выровненными файлами в моём представлении, например при сжатии таблиц в СУБД (в зависимости от форматов файлов конечно)... в изначальном предложении упоминались нелинейные меаредакторы, но я не знаю видеоформатов, где кадры/какие-то блоки были бы выровнены на 2^N...  и да, под «не имеет аналогов» я подразумеваю не плюс для конкретной ОС, а жирный минус для всего подхода...

Comment: @freim не стоит всем рассказывать о своём  непонимании базовых вещей управления памятью в современных ОС.

Comment: А вот кстати еще можно вспомнить о [разреженных файлах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) - они делают абсолютно то же самое, то есть освобождают кластеры в любом месте файла, но при этом внутренняя адресация файла не изменяется, и при необходимости область на диске автоматически резервируется опять. На мой взгляд, такое решение  гораздо лучше, чем грубое вырезание области.

Comment: @freim, это не тоже самое... области применения различаются и применение одного подхода не исключает другой...

Comment: Я большой разницы не вижу, но спорить не буду. Замечу только напоследок, что разреженные файлы в реальных приложениях практически не используются. Думаю, у физического вырезания кластеров шансы на популярность еще ближе к нулю.